# Chaining Telethon start methods

Tags: python, telethon

I have been using telethon for a long time with two clients, one for a bot (with bot token) and another for my user (using phone).

I always thought two separate clients were necessary *(are them?)* but I recently saw this in the documentation:
[image]
https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.auth.AuthMethods.start

But when I go to test it I got:

```
UserWarning:

the session already had an authorized user so it did not login to the user account using the provided phone (it may not be using the user you expect)
```

So I don't understand if the example indicates that I can have a single client to control a bot and a userbot, if one `start(...)` overrides the other or if the documentation example is wrong directly.

On the other hand, if I use that example code (including the last `with` part) I get:

```
RuntimeError: You must use "async with" if the event loop is running (i.e. you are inside an "async def")
```

And lastly, my ide was warning me when passing a phone as a string because it expected `typing.Callable[[], str]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says "*initialization* can be chained". Initialization is this line:

```py
client = TelegramClient(...)
```

and you can chain `.start()` there:

```py
client = await TelegramClient(...).start(...)
```

but it doesn't mean you can chain multiple calls to `start()`. Indeed, if you want to control more than one account, you will need separate clients.